# Discriminant analysis with only one independent variables in R

Tags: r, classification, data-visualization, discriminant-analysis, multi-class

I have one categorical variable with 12 classes (t) and one independent continuous variable (x1). One of the classes of the categorical variable is the reference class. I want to apply discriminant analysis to this bivariate data set. However, I cannot draw a graph because it has only one independent variable. How can I apply discriminant analysis to this data set, see class distinctions and draw graphics?

Comment: You can use the MclustDA procedure in R.

Comment: How many observations? Can you share with us a plot, maybe color-code the classes and plot it as a stripchart [one example here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93605/plotting-part-of-data-using-violin-plot-and-the-other-part-as-stripchart-stripp) with the 12 classes at different y plotting positions? Also consider share (a link to) the data!

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is with making a plot.  Why not make some boxplots to start (`boxplot(x1~t)`)?  There are *lots* of options here. Consider posting an example dataset.

Comment: Mathematically such discriminant analysis will be linearly equivalent (related) to one-way ANOVA. But it looks like the Q is not about DA, it is about plotting.